# Creating XML file in PHP file is empty

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

Once again I need your help dear StackOverflow community.

I'm trying to pass data from WordPress custom query and create an XML file to finally generate a google map with multiple markers.

So far I got to the part where I pass the data and I'm generating the xml file. I have looked up in the console if the xml is generated and its empty:

```
<markers>
 <marker name="Array">
  <marker name="Array">
   <marker name="Array"></marker>
  </marker>
 </marker>
</markers>
```

My code looks like this:

```
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
      echo '<markers>';

      $args = array('post_type' => 'investments'); $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); {} {

        $postsData[$row]['meta'][$i] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'investments_location_details', true );
        $postsData[$row]['title'][$i] = [
          'id' => get_the_id(),
          'title' => get_the_title()
        ];

      }

      foreach($postsData as $key => $value) :
        $title = $value['title'];
        $meta = $value['meta'];

        $ind=0;

          echo '<marker ';
          echo 'name="'. $value['title'] . '" ';
          if (isset($meta[$key]['lat']) && is_array($meta[$key]['lat'])) { // merge
              echo 'lat="' . $meta[$key]['lat'] . '" ';
          }
          if (isset($meta[$key]['lng']) && is_array($meta[$key]['lng'])) { // merge
              echo 'lng="' . $meta[$key]['lng'] . '" ';
          }
          echo '/>';

        $ind = $ind + 1;

      endforeach;

      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();

      echo '</markers>';
```

I did a var_dump after `$ind = $ind + 1;` and the values were printed. What could be the reason they where not added to the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The save_post hook gets called each time a post is created or updated. Just hook into that. There you can do something like

```
 fputcsv('/tmp/' . $post_id, $post) or output to XML/JSON.
```